# Using the hypothetical and non standard word "manywhere"

Tags: word-request

I have frequently used **"manywhere"** to describe "many places" instead of "everywhere".

- In increasing order: `nowhere < somewhere < manywhere < everywhere`

It seems to be an elegant and logical solution to a missing language element, doesn't it?   The following fictional dialog demonstrates my thinking. (This is not *factual*):

- "Have you heard about the ritual of hanging a voodoo doll on buildings under construction to keep away negative energy?"

  "Yeah, I saw that **somewhere** in my home town of New York City."

  "Well in India, you can find that **manywhere**."

  "**Manywhere**?"

  "Yes. That's a logical word I made. Not everywhere. Many places have it! That better describes the meaning, does it not?"

  "Hmmm.  I guess it does.  I never really thought about it like that!"

**Manywhere** has some modern and historical usage:

- Google Search: [manywhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=manywhere&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS550US550&oq=manywhere&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j0l2.2936j0j9&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)
- Google Ngram: [manywhere](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=manywhere&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,manywhere;,c0).

**So my questions are:**

- Why is this missing in English?  What if someone wants to say more than somewhere but less than everywhere?
- Are there situations when/where this word could be used?
- What would be good/bad right/wrong effective/ineffective in "introducing" manywhere into standard English? (If one actually could do such a thing.)
- I think it would be a great word! Am I missing something?
- It seems to me that the opposite of somewhere (at some places) is manywhere (at many places) and NOT nowhere. It broadens the scope.  Does that make sense?

<sub>*(Credit to @CoolHandLouis for editing help.)*</sub>

Comment: The question is certainly too broad, in my opinion. *Why doesn't English have this as common use?* is not something that can be answered definitively (unless it were a word that was in use but now is not). *Are there situations when/where this word could be used?* Of course: in informal usage, where you believe your audience would understand it. As for *"introducing" manywhere into standard English* Introduction of a word into standard usage (aka "the dictionary") depends on a large number of people adopting a new word and using it enough and in certain ways over a period of time.

Comment: This video explains the process the Merriam Webster dictionary goes through to decide what words should be added: See http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/0032-howaword.htm?&t=1392566357 PS the word in question represents a "semantic gap" - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_gap for interesting reading.

Comment: I have edited the question to better focus it on the theoretical manywhere question, and to improve readability. Also, added dialog back in, *in the spirit of the theoretical aspect of the question*. I did not change the question at all... just refocused it a bit better. @MaulikV: Note that <br> doesn't work in the manner you have been using it.  Use two spaces at the end of a line. [Basic Formatting Help](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 11):

In the first place, you are constructing a false parallel. *Somewhere* does not mean “at some [=indefinite number of] places [plural]”; it means “at some [=indefinite] place [singular]”. *I read that somewhere*, for instance, does not mean “I read that in a small number of sources” but “I read that in at least one place which I cannot (or will not) at this moment identify”.

In the second place, history demonstrates that *manywhere* is ‘an elegant and logical solution’ to a problem ***which does not exist.*** Take a look at the Google Ngram display (I have had Google graph the incidence of *manywhere* as a proportion of the incidence of *manywhere* to *anywhere*, to give a clearer indication of frequency):

[image]

Over the past 100 years there's one spike at around 5,000:1, and a couple more at 17,000:1 or less. The 1902-1903 spike is particularly interesting. Henry James floated the word in an 1894 short story (other early hits are false positives), but it was Lord Avebury (Sir John Lubbock), a distinguished banker and politician and writer on archaeology and evolution, who successfully launched it in *The Scenery of England*, 1902, where he tossed off the sentence ‘Smoothed and polished rocks occur also “manywhere”, if I may coin the word, in our northern districts…’

The coinage excited considerable comment in newspapers and journals; this is representative:

> The new word “manywhere” will undoubtedly find as ready application in adwriting as it has in newspaper offices and general literature, for it is a genuinely useful word, giving expression to an idea that has heretofore had no symbol. It was coined by Lord Avebury, the noted British scientist, and used in a recent book on geology as a fillgap between “somewhere” and  “everywhere.”  While freely criticized by philologers, it is generally thought that “manywhere” will eventually attain a place in the dictionary.    —*Printers Ink, a journal for advertisers*, June 3, 1903

The word had a brief vogue (mainly among geologists, ethnologists and, as *Printers Ink* predicted, adwriters), but eventually disappeared again. In this respect it contrasts significantly with two other words coined by Lord Avebury: *neolithic* and *paleolithic*, which are still in use.

I'll leave it to others to explore the tiny post-WWI and post-WWII spikes; but it’s pretty clear that however useful *manywhere* may appear in theory, the speaking, hearing, reading and writing public has no practical need for it.

This should not discourage you from employing *manywhere* as a peculiarly expressive member of your own lexicon. Its meaning is transparent, so you need not fear misunderstanding; and it strikes me as a cheerful sort of word, which could lend a spritely air to your discourse. You might even create a new vogue for it—and perhaps Lord Avebury was a century ahead of his public, and now is the time for the word to enter common parlance.

Comment: This is useful. Trust me, I have been using *manywhere* for years! And I had never looked/referred any other source for that. It just came natural and obvious (to me!).

Comment: @MaulikV: Well, you're in good company: Henry James, Max Beerbohm, Oscar Wilde. But you should be aware that it will always be taken as a jocular nonce-word.

Comment: You're answer expressed many sentiments I had on this. I did a lot of research for the edit and came to some similar conclusions. I see @MaulikV as a person who is as excited about his invention/discovery of this word as Lord Avebury was in 1902. He **believes** in the word. He's...almost...evangelical. His original question was a bit of a platform for his opinion. <LightHeartedTone>He's not "going down easy".</LightHeartedTone> I think there's much more that could be said about it.  I don't want it to stop with one "correct" answer.

Comment: @MaulikV: I love this question. Marking an answer correct has an effect of quelling further discussion since it's no longer "unanswered". **Would you please unmark StoneyB's question as the correct one?** I'm being funny and sincere asking that. It's funny because it would normally be egregious to ask an OP to "unmark a correct answer". And I'm boldly assuming that StoneyB would not mind. I really wanted to highlight this question of yours so it could get more attention. Because I think a lot of people would be interested in this. You've raised a fascinating question. Why not manywhere?