# Constructing a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

In order to mention another detail about items in one sentence, can I directly say like the following sentence:

> we count the number of techniques used for efficient result.

I want to mean that techniques are used for efficient result. **NOT** the number of [...] are used for efficient result.

Again, to be clear, I want to enclose the sentence like this:

> [we count the number of [techniques used for efficient result.]]

**NOT** like that:

> [we count [the number of techniques used for efficient result.]]

is this a correct approach to mention what the techniques are in one sentence?

***ADDED***: It has been made clear to me that the sentence I should be asking about is this:

> We *count **on a** number* of techniques used for efficient result.

Comment: It's still unclear to me. Do you mean *you used several techniques to obtain efficient results?*

Comment: I really want to mention only the techniques themselves are useful for an efficient result, not the number of techniques.

Comment: Then don't use it! *The techniques used to obtain efficient results.* Or you mean you *count on* (rely on) a number of techniques to obtain efficient results?

Comment: but I want to mention in one sentence that we count each of them and they are useful.

Comment: Out of context, I'd read it as *we count the number of [techniques used for efficient result]*, as you suggested. I think both *techniques (which we've) used to obtain efficient results* and *techniques (which we've) used for efficient results* work. However, if it's about a specific result in particular, and you've employed a number of techniques to reach such result, I might rephrase it to *We (have) [employ(ed)|use(d)] a number of techniques [for|to obtain] the efficient result*.

Comment: What we're having difficulty with is the verb *count*. **1)** By itself *count* means "determine the quantity of"; if this is your meaning, then you do not count "the number", you count "the techniques" to arrive at a number: 4 or 7 or 123. **2)** *Count **on*** means to "rely on" or "depend on"; if this is your meaning, you probably mean ***a** number of*, in the sense "many" or "several". **3)** It is also possible that you have been misled by your dictionary and are using *count* to mean *list*. Use *list* to tell your readers  you are going to name all the techniques. Which do you mean?

Comment: I mean the second one you explained @StoneyB

Comment: I was going to edit your question to reflect this; but that would make @CoolHandLouis' answer to the original form nonsensical, so I am going to add this at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We count on a number of techniques used for efficient result.

In this revised version of your sentence there is no ambiguity. The expression ***a*** number of is understood as a fixed-form quantifier, equivalent to “many” or ”several”. Consequently, this sentence will not be misunderstood in the particular way you fear.

However, it is still not a very good sentence, especially in a formal context, where language must be used with a maximum of precision.

First, some relatively minor points:

- *For efficient result* is unidiomatic; we say either *for **an** efficient result* (article with singular) or *for efficient results* (no article with plural). It doesn’t matter much which you use.
- A matter you have to be careful about is the common colloquial use of *efficient* to mean  *effective*. *Efficient* means that your work involves no wasted effort; *effective* means that you arrive at the result you are seeking rather than at something else. We do not have sufficient context to judge which you mean.
- There is some redundancy in the two expressions *rely on* and *used for*—both include the notion of a technique (or several techniques) being needed to achieve the desired result.
- *A number of* (or *several* or *many*) is unnecessarily vague. You know how many techniques you have employed; why should you conceal this from your readers? It is simple courtesy to let your readers know exactly how many techniques they will have to deal with.

There are also two major points:

- *Efficient* [or *effective*] *result* is a very dubious expression. Without more context it is impossible to know exactly what you *should* be saying; but I think it very unlikely that the *result* which you are aiming at is itself *efficient* [or *effective*]. What you probably mean is that you have developed a methodology which permits you arrive at the result in an efficient [or effective] manner.
- The most serious problem is that it is not clear whether the multiple techniques you are talking about are **individually** efficient [or effective] in reaching the desired result or are efficient [or effective] only when **all** are used. I suspect (from your use of *count on*) that you mean the latter. You must let your readers know which you mean. Here are two contrasting examples:

  > Any of five different techniques may be used to achieve the result efficiently [or effectively].
  >
  > Five different techniques are all required to to achieve the result efficiently [or effectively].

Note, by the way, that only the first two points above are matters of English usage. The others are equally valid in **any** language: they reflect the [**Adamantine Law of Written Language**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7503/32):

> Anything which **can** be misunderstood **will** be.