# Using past continuous for future event, is it for formality?

Tags: past-continuous

There's a sentence taken from Hewing's book (the writer of Advanced Grammar in Use):

> **Write v if the italicized parts are correct. If they are wrong, correct them.**
>
> We *are meeting* at seven in the Globe coffee bar. Can you be there,
> too?

The key answer says it's correct, but it also says that *were meeting* is also possible, although there's no further explanation.

Also here is related [discussion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7499/can-the-past-continuous-be-used-for-future-events) about this problem, but it still hasn't answered my question whether it has something to do with politeness or an event involving the past. However I can't see the past sense in that sentence above. If it's for politeness, then why **can you...** instead of **could you...**?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey edited

Comment: Been 3 hours, still -1 plus 1 close voter and no answers. What else should I give? I've told the name of the book, I've given the related discussion. Which part is not clear? Just tell me! it's just that if I was smart, I wouldn't ask here.  You make enthusiastic students discouraged instead of helping!

Comment: I would find it odd to use _were meeting_ in this context.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Absolutely! And you should develop into a complete answer. I can't understand the question was downvoted. *We were meeting* here means  *we had planned/had intended to*.

Comment: I personally don't understand the question was downvoted because this is not an obvious meaning.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey They researched on the site at least (even if it's a different question). And frankly this is not the type of thing that is widely documented...

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Because **you** know what key words to use (e.g. planning, uncertainty, etc.) if the OP doesn't know planning or intention or uncertainty is involved here, it's not that easy.